# How do I remove a category?

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

The Updates sub-category is very annoying and I rarely access it.  It takes up space and is unnecessary for what I need. How can I remove it?

Comment: you cant remove category, but you can hide it

Answer (score 3):

- click on the gear icon
- go to **Settings**
- select **Labels**
- scroll down to **Categories**
- hide them all (or just one you want)

[image]